# Windows 7 Wildcard Expansion

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd, wildcard, windows-7-x64

I just tried the command `dir pod* /s/a` from within the `d:\dump` directory and got the below output. How are the `posix` and `poppler` folders valid matches for the `pod*` wildcard? I am using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Is this a bug in Windows 7 or is my computer infected with a virus?

```
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 024E-6214

 Directory of D:\dump

05/28/2013  11:37 AM    <DIR>          podofo
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of D:\dump\pgsql\share\timezone\Europe

08/16/2012  04:54 PM             1,931 Podgorica
               1 File(s)          1,931 bytes

 Directory of D:\dump\php-5.2.17\ext\posix\tests

11/25/2009  09:23 AM             1,146 posix_setuid_variation3.phpt
11/24/2009  02:54 AM               692 posix_errno_variation2.phpt
12/05/2008  07:47 PM             2,987 posix_strerror_variation1.phpt
06/11/2009  06:00 PM               495 posix_getpwnam_basic.phpt
04/11/2008  03:02 PM               739 posix_times_error.phpt
08/26/2009  10:47 PM               634 posix_ttyname_variation2.phpt
               6 File(s)          6,693 bytes

 Directory of D:\dump\podofo

03/04/2013  12:11 PM         4,938,072 podofo.pdf
               1 File(s)      4,938,072 bytes

 Directory of D:\dump\poppler\poppler-0.22.4\cpp

12/31/2012  04:13 AM            17,953 poppler-document.cpp
12/31/2012  04:13 AM             1,801 poppler-image.h
               2 File(s)         19,754 bytes

 Directory of D:\dump\poppler\poppler-0.22.4\glib

12/31/2012  04:13 AM             7,509 poppler-attachment.cc
               1 File(s)          7,509 bytes

 Directory of D:\dump\poppler\poppler-0.22.4\qt4\src

12/31/2012  04:13 AM             6,790 poppler-ps-converter.cc
03/26/2013  03:18 AM            10,451 poppler-form.cc
12/31/2012  04:13 AM            12,327 poppler-optcontent.cc
02/21/2013  01:39 AM             1,564 poppler-qiodeviceoutstream.cc
               4 File(s)         31,132 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
              15 File(s)      5,005,091 bytes
               1 Dir(s)  52,250,210,304 bytes free
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the `/x` switch to your `DIR` command, and all will be revealed.

`/x` shows the short and long names for the file. `DIR` matches on either.

Comment: Thanks! That explains a lot. Shocking!